# I want the min number of the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know why i have a syntax error.
I need to get the minim number of the column salario from empleados.
I comment line per line and the error appears on the while

[Error syntax image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR4lU.png)

Please help, thanks

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `empresa`.`Minim` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `empresa`.`Minim` () RETURNS INT
BEGIN

declare numregs int;
declare i int default 0;
declare v_minim int default 0;
declare v_salario int default 0;

declare cminim cursor for select salario from empleados;

select count(*) into numregs from empleados;

open cminim;

while i<numregs do
  fetch cminim into v_salario;
  if i=0 then
    v_minim=v_salario;
  end if;
  if i>0 and v_salario<v_minim then
      v_minim=v_salario;
  end if;
  i=i+1;
end while;

return v_minim;

close cminim;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?  You have both tagged.

Comment: mysql <> sql server. This is clearly not sql server code, I've removed sql server tag. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Why not simply `select min(salario) from empleados`, i.e. no need for that loop.

Comment: Probably a crazy question but why don't you just `SELECT MIN(salario) FROM empleados`?

Comment: @jarlh great minds think alike!

Comment: Apart from the missing `SET`s which have been mentioned in an answer, by defaulting `v_minim` to 0 the output of your function will always be 0 (unless of course you have some employees who have to pay to work i.e. negative salaries). You should default `v_minim` to a number which you know will be higher than the highest salary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The error has show itself clearly,the reason is that **when you assign value of the variable ,you missing the keywork** `set`.

You need to use `set` keyword to assign value

```
while i<numregs do
  fetch cminim into v_salario;
  if i=0 then
    set v_minim=v_salario; -- use set
  end if;
  if i>0 and v_salario<v_minim then
      set v_minim=v_salario;
  end if;
  set i=i+1;
end while;
```